# Quickbooks Online Authentication issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to switch my website from using the v2 api with Quickbooks Online to v3, but I keep getting this:

```
<IntuitResponse time="2016-07-10T18:53:00.651-07:00" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <Fault type="AUTHENTICATION">
        <Error code="3200">
            <Message>message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401</Message>
            <Detail>SignatureBaseString: POST&amp;https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F1312417415%2Fcustomer&amp;oauth_consumer_key%3D**********%26oauth_nonce%3D45120952%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1468201980%26oauth_token%3D***********%26oauth_version%3D1.0</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

I've gone and tried it on the API Explorer and API calls work, which tells me it probably has to do with my tokens. But I can't figure it out. I'm using a standard OAuth library (it's for Python on Google App Engine). I saw this page in the docs:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/0015_calling_data_services#/Company_id

I tried doing as it said under "The Authorization Header" section and formatted my header identically, but it still gives me the same error. I've refreshed my OAuth tokens several times. I'm currently trying to accomplish this in a sandbox account and suspect I am somehow using the wrong tokens/credentials. I've seen several cases similar to mine, but usually a little different. Can anyone relate to / help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Dev app keys in your code will work to connect to sandbox accounts.
The base url will be sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com which is correct but please check your keys in the config.

Prod app keys in your code will work to connect to QBO Prod accounts.
The base url will be quickbooks.api.intuit.com